# android: how to get broadcasted messages from service when activity is in background

Tags: android, service

I have a service and an activity. in service I broadcast messages received from network and in the activity show these messages. this works fine. but all messages will lost when the activity is in the background.

How can I get last messages(if exists) from server, in activity onResume(or onCreate)?

**EDIT :**
in service:

```
public class server extends Service implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startID)
    {   
        //initializing socket and begining listen
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        String readed;
        while (true)
        {
            if(reader == null) continue;
            try
            {
                if ((readed = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SEND_DATA_INTENT);
                    intent.putExtra("type", "message");
                    intent.putExtra("content", readed.substring(1));
                    sendBroadcast(intent);
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ee) { }
        }
    }
}
```

and in activity:

```
public class menhaj extends Activity
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        if (dataUpdateReceiver == null) dataUpdateReceiver = new DataReciver();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(server.SEND_DATA_INTENT);
        registerReceiver(dataUpdateReceiver, intentFilter);
        super.onResume();
    };

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        if (dataUpdateReceiver != null) unregisterReceiver(dataUpdateReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    };

    private class DataReciver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(server.SEND_DATA_INTENT))
            {
                Bundle bdl = intent.getExtras();
                String type = bdl.getString("type");
                if (type.equals("message"))
                {
                    String message = bdl.getString("content");
                    db.addMessage(message);
                    showMessage(message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If that activity is in the background, the user probably doesn't want to see messages from it.  Show notifications from your services instead. Generally, an activity should de-register itself `onPause()` and register again `onResume()` when it comes back to the foreground.

Comment: +1, yes, but there are wrong programming paradigm or request from managers, when you need to show a google map or do something which bring the app to background. I can't raise always the StupidBossOrClientException :)

Comment: Set your managers straight :) You can show your map, etc. by clicking on the notification. Unless this is absolutely critical (hurricane/earthquake coming, etc.), never a good idea to just pop up another app while the user is doing something else (which might as well be more important).

Comment: thanks, but in my case user must see all messages from manager(pc server) in activity.

Comment: Show some code and explain what you mean by 'broadcast'. BTW, they will still see the messages (eventually) even if shown as notifications. Also, how exactly are messages 'lost'?

Comment: Well, since you unregister the receiver `onPause()`, it will naturally not receive anything once after that. If you really want to got that way, make the receiver a regular public class, register it in the manifest and have it start your notification activity using `startActivity()`. Or just start the activity from the service. Generally, though, a service that runs all the time is a bad thing and a battery drain.

Comment: No, I don't want to start activity whenever a message receives. I want when user starts activity, he can see all messages that received before.

Comment: This is a different thing altogether. Have your receiver save messages in a database, then show them when the activity starts and mark them as read/shown, so that they are not shown again next time.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21778/discussion-between-ali-m-and-nikolay-elenkov)

Answer (score 0):

I would declare BroadcastReceivers , those can receive messages and bring back to from your avtivity / app